# Why is this request returning 405 Method Not Allowed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http

Requests to my API were going swimmingly until I had to POST data. API is expecting JSON so I changed my `content-type` to `application/json`, and this causes all [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) implementations to require [preflights](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), and now I'm getting 405. Thing is, request/response looks good. Request headers accept, content-type are in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers`. Request method `POST`, `POST` and `PUT` allowed. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) allowing all origins. What gives?

```
Remote Address: -
Request URL: -
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headers
  Accept: */*
  */// for the sake of syntax highlighting
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
  Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
  Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Connection: keep-alive
  Host: -
  Origin: http://localhost
  Pragma: no-cache
  Referer: http://localhost/
Response Headers
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Allow: POST,PUT
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Length: 76
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Date: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 19:43:56 GMT
  Expires: -1
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

[canjs issue](http://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/111)

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this but doesn't that say your request method is OPTIONS not POST

Comment: Yup, and the response says that only POST and PUT are allowed.

Comment: Yes, so that's what a preflight request is. Since it's a CORS request, it's asking if POST is an accepted method. But you may be on to someting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Related StackOverflow Posts**

These posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293782/mvc-web-api-405-method-not-allowed), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160367/asp-net-web-api-ajax-put-405-method-not-allowed-entity-framework)) say to [enable CORS on WebApi using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) and offers an [implementation of WebApiConfig.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23311611/517676).

These posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162825/web-api-put-request-generates-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807331/405-message-method-not-allowed-with-web-api)) say to remove WebDAV by adding this inside `<system.webServer>`.

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV"/>
</handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```